# How can I unfreeze a room in chat room for a new similar use?

Tags: support, chat

How can I unfreeze a room in chat room for a new similar use?
I created a chat-room about a problem in Mathematics chat rooms long ago. It had frozen. Now I want to unfreeze it for a new problem similar to last one. Address is [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/12021). Thanks.

Comment: Related question on meta.SO: [How do I unfreeze a frozen chat room?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70198/how-do-i-unfreeze-a-frozen-chat-room).

Comment: @MartinSleziak I searched it in math. sorry for inaction. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only moderators can unfreeze chat rooms, fortunately there are a lot of chat.SE moderators as every moderator on *any* SE site is also a chat moderator. Just ask any moderator you know to unfreeze.

In this case, just link the chat room in your post and I can unfreeze it.

Comment: I see you've already unfrozen the room. Thanks.